# Install VQmod for Opencart2.0.x.x

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

I searched on Google 
I find old versions correctly but for Opencart 2.0 + i didn't find anything
.
https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod

Using FTP, upload the "vqmod" folder from the zip to the root of your opencart store
After this 
Goto http://www.yoursite.com/vqmod/install

Not get any success message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest releases of VQMod are found [here](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/releases). The one you want is the *opencart* one NOT the *stand alone* one. Click the first .zip file under the `Downloads` subheading. The latest version is [this one](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/releases/download/v2.5.1-opencart.zip/vqmod-2.5.1-opencart.zip)

Answer (score 1):

i have a solution simple 5 step

1.Download LocalCopy.zip

- http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18892

2.unzip in install from extenstion installer in admin panel

3.Download Vqmod installer http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=22378&filter_search=VQMOD

4.install from extenstion installer

5.Vqmod will be install

Note:in case you get error of ftp than set ftp from store->setting->ftp and if get error in step 4 than uninstall LocalCopy extenstion and install again extenstion installer

if you still get problem contact me